# According to book "Wonder"

Tags: meaning-in-context, books

The author wrote " But I'm kind of used to how I look by now. I know how to pretend I don't see the faces people make."
I don't understand two sentences, can u explain it to me? And what does "Look by" mean?

Answer (score 1):

You're parsing the first sentence wrong by breaking things up into the wrong parts. You're asking what "look by" means, when that's not a phrase when you break down how that sentenced is parsed. I'm not an English teacher, just a native speaker, so I apologize if I don't know the formal names for the different parts of the sentence, but the sentence "I'm sort of used to how I look by now" is broken into three parts "I'm sort of used to" "how I look" and "by now". Another way of phrasing it by putting those parts into a different order would be "By now, how I look is something I'm sort of used to". What it's saying is that at the current point of time ("By now"), they have become accustomed to ("sort of used to") the manner of their appearance ("how I look").

The second sentence goes on to elaborate on the first: the way that they became accustomed to their appearance is by pretending not to notice the looks of revulsion that other people make when they see them.

Comment: I understood it now. Thank you so much!